Entity Framework and slow process of generating model with nested classes using TPH approach
The Tech Stack is Code First, EF 6.4, .NET Framework 4.8, with an MS SQL database.
Here's the issue: the database model in the code is based on the TPH approach (Table Per Hierarchy), where we have dozens (and here's the problem) of small subclasses inheriting from a single base class, either directly or indirectly.
For example, we have a class Activity, then a subclass Training which inherits from Activity, followed by a class like DailyActivity, then HomeActivity, and then perhaps SoloActivity, and finally something like PlayingXbox, which is the entity representation in the database. All previous classes are abstract, so they've been used here as, in my opinion, interfaces to classify types of activities. These examples are from my head, but the principle remains the same because we have multiple inheritance across different branches, resulting in dozens of types and groups.
Now, on the first call to the database, EF enters the database model mapping mode and essentially dies. It hangs and takes several minutes. Once it maps, subsequent calls are fast and trouble-free. The issue is only with that initial cold call during which the mapping is performed. It seems that the deeper EF goes into mapping and the more class types it has to map, the longer this process takes.
When I cut out one branch with the most subtypes and classes, mapping time dropped from several minutes to a few seconds. Moreover, mapping entities at the 7-8th level from the main class takes about 3-4 seconds, while mapping a class at the first level takes only a few milliseconds. Therefore, the depth in the class tree is significantly impactful.
My question is, has anyone encountered something like this?
On EF forums, they usually suggest updating to EF Core and don't really tackle this issue. They just mention that EF has performance problems with mapping when using TPH. But maybe someone here has seen something like this and can point out a direction.
I know that one solution is to remove all intermediate classes, create interfaces, and group classes and functionalities based on those. But before I do that, I want to check if there are other solutions, like "turn off something in the configuration," or "it's because EF materializes objects, and if you turn this on or off or set this, it will reduce the mapping time from several minutes to a few seconds".
To Clarify: I use Pregeneratd Views by EF Tools. It takes around 4 mins to generate them. It uses thema s they can catch breakpoint, but using them decreased time of cold call from 4 mins to 3 min 40 secs whic is some improvement but i dont think this si the root of the problem.

EF6 lets you cache the type-mapping files, that might help. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/pre-generated-views

Did this already.. dropped from 4 mins to ,3 mins and 40 secs. So not much difference. generating views is not an issue i think but maybe materialising object??

Have you used your profiler to see where the time is actually being spent? I know you said "on the first call to the database, EF enters the database model mapping mode and essentially dies. It hangs and takes several minutes." - but can you be more specific, such as showing us the stack-traces where it seemingly goes slowly?

EF doesn't map in those 4 minutes, it generates prepared statements. If you have a lot of entities and complex mappings (and at the 7-8th level  is extremely unusual even for in-memory objects), that step takes longer. An inheritance hierarchy 8 levels deep would be a warning sign in any application. It's quite possible that inheritance is used when eg composition or just a single Kind column would be a better option.

Do all those subclasses have different persisted properties? Do they really have to be stored in different tables? PlayingXbox sounds like a single row in an Activities table with a Location column of InHome, a Participants of 1, a reference to a Schedules table and Playing XBox perhaps as just a label. Different application behavior doesn't mean there are different actual entities. There are several design patterns that separate structure from behavior

Well i knwo how it should be done. And this project i inherited so looking for quick fixes. i might hear from you gusy that is is normal and nothing i can do about, but maybe someone will sell me some tip that will be fixing the issue without rewriting the code much. With Profiler are youa sking me fro some specific line of the code or something more than that. never used VS profiles. just SQL ones so dont know what you want me to provide

@SzalonyFacet "I might hear from you guys that is is normal and there is nothing I can do about it" - Quite the opposite: this is not normal, and you should be able to fix this.

@SzalonyFacet re: VS Profiler (Main Menu > Debug > Performance Profiler). It will start your application and trace every method call made. After you've collected enough data it will show you tables showing all the functions where the most time was spent, including private/internal methods inside .NET framework and EF assemblies. Whatever the cause of the problem is, in all liklihood it should be obvious from whatever the tables show - but if you're still stuck then copy+paste the tables into your quesiton-post.

I wonder if you need inheritance in the first place. IMO all these different activities don't merit different classes. I wouldn't be surprised to see that a simple Type column/property without any inheritance would suffice to filter data and hook on other behavioral patterns for the differences in behavior, if there even are any.

well. matter of question here is how to fix slow loading EF model without restructuring approach. Im 100% sure that rewriting this aprt of the system will fix the problem. but rewrting will take around 2-3 weeks of work so want to avoid for now if i can.

@SzalonyFacet Run the profiler and find out...
